cannot download my custom library from my git repository
I have pushed my local react project to a repository "redoctrik/redoctrik-react-dropdownlist".
This is the repository folder structure:
Components
--dropdownlist
----index.js
----styles.css
index.js

i tried:
npm i redoctrik/redoctrik-react-dropdownlist

But i get this error:
    PS C:\Users\tp_re\source\repos\bulletcontrols> npm i redoctrik/redoctrik-react-dropdownlist
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\tp_re\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneXXXXXXqKVafl/package.json
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tp_re\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneXXXXXXqKVafl\package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\tp_re\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-24T04_40_38_072Z-debug-0.log


You need to clone the repo git clone https://github.com/redoctrik/redoctrik-react-dropdownlist instead of installing it as an NPM module.

why do i need to clone?

i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KV5XFwfvnEI, and i used github instead of adding the library to npm, becuase my github repository is private aswell

why cant i use npm?

what I'm trying to do is create react components and sell them, so I used GitHub as a private repository. So if i do this signing up with npm and purchasing a package so that i can make my packages private i would have to go with the npm packaging instead of GitHub so that users can download the package using npm?

@redoc01 "why do i need to clone?" "why cant i use npm?" because you never published the package to npm, why are you expecting it to install it from github, which is completely unrelated to npm. now, you can publish it to the github package registry, but you need to set it up
